# UIWebView images in application documents folder not refreshing

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiwebview, image

I have a UIWebView where I display dynamically generated HTML via

```
[_webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:applicationDocumentsDirectory];
```

The HTML contains images such as `<img src="chart1.png">`. Each time the HTML is generated, the images are also freshly generated. (I have checked that they are indeed in the right location and updated.) However, after the first run, if I change the data and relaunch my UIWebView, it uses the old images.

I have tried:

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
```

to no avail. (Not surprising, maybe, as this relates to NSURLRequests.)

I know that there is the possibility of absolute URLs, but I have not tried this at it seems cumbersome and I want it to work with these simple relative URLs. The issue is not finding the images but updating them appropriately.

I also know that you could invent some scheme tricking the browser into thinking that the image is dynamic by changing the `src` to something like `chart1.png?1234` where the number is random generated and always unique. This also seems like a useless workaround for an issue that should be simple to solve.

Any ideas?

Comment: I had the same issue, UIWebView is caching the image. 
I have change the name of image on every reload (By adding time stamp) and it started working. 

Try, this might work.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a proper reference to the image, otherwise it may not work. If you have the image and the html file in the same level then try using something like this,

```
<img src="./chart1.png">
```

Or if you want the images inside the folder then refer it using the proper path reference to it.

I hope it works.

Comment: Nice try. This does not make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

hi i was having a similar problem with uiwebview whenever i loaded a previously loaded page old content was displayed. after investigating further i found that uiwebview content is loaded in the background and then displayed after its finished loading; however while it is loading old content is displayed. I fixed my problem by making my own uiwebview loading delegates and adding my own loading symbol insteaad of displaying old content.

```
    -(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{

webView.hidden = true;
loader.animationImages =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:

                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"]
                             ,nil];


loader.animationDuration = 1.5;

loader.animationRepeatCount = 100;
[loader startAnimating];

}
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{

[loader stopAnimating];
webView.hidden  = false;
}
```

remember to link the delegates and all that other stuff
i hope this helps :)

Comment: Sorry, this does not apply either. The HTML string that is loaded has e.g. different text, the different text is displayed. Only the images are not. The images are generated *before* the text is.

Answer (score -1):

You need to provide the absolute path of the image source.

```
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                  @"/chart1.png" ];
```

I hope this works

Comment: In the question it says clearly that I need relative paths. Duh.

Comment: you can use <img src="../chart1.png">. ".." represents the enclosing folder of chart1 image.